# Google Sheets ImportXML XPath - sum vs avg

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets

Gurus of GoogleSheets/ImportXML/XPath coding,

Quick question... two ImportXML statements with the only difference being the XPath Aggregate function:  sum works, avg doesn't.

```
=ImportXML("http://api.eve-marketdata.com/api/item_orders2.xml?char_name=Demo&buysell=b&type_ids=17464&station_ids=60003760","sum(/emd/result/rowset/row[not(preceding-sibling::row/@price > @price or following-sibling::row/@price > @price)]/@volremaining)")

=ImportXML("http://api.eve-marketdata.com/api/item_orders2.xml?char_name=Demo&buysell=b&type_ids=17464&station_ids=60003760","avg(/emd/result/rowset/row[not(preceding-sibling::row/@price > @price or following-sibling::row/@price > @price)]/@volremaining)")
```

NOTE:  For the page in the formula, there goal is to find the row with the highest @price... then get the quantity/volremaining and price.  However, when there are multiple rows at the highest price, I need to sum(@volremaining) and avg(@price) since I only want one row returned.  I can use the [1] offset to get this value...

```
=ImportXML("http://api.eve-marketdata.com/api/item_orders2.xml?char_name=Demo&buysell=b&type_ids=17464&station_ids=60003760","/emd/result/rowset/row[not(preceding-sibling::row/@price > @price or following-sibling::row/@price > @price)][1]/@volremaining")
```

... but the exercise to get min()/max()/avg() to work is failing.

Can't for the life of me figure out the difference, other than the [W3C XPath Site](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp) shows fn:avg with double brackets ((arg1,arg2,arg3)), while fn:sum is single brackets (arg1,arg2,arg3).

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

G A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheet's `IMPORTXML()` function is exceptionally buggy, but in this case the reason is different.

`IMPORTXML()` only supports XPath 1.0 functions, but not XPath 2.0 ones. `sum()` is an XPath 1.0 function, whereas `avg()`, `min()` and `max()` are XPath 2.0 functions that you cannot use in Google Sheets.

See the [relevant part of the XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions) - as you can see, `avg()` is not listed as a number function. It is only listed as a member of the [XPath 2.0 and XQuery aggregate functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#aggregate-functions). By the way, w3schools has nothing to do with W3C - and you should never ever trust content from w3schools.

To sum this up, `avg()` is not available in an XPath expression - just retrieve all values and use a [Google Sheets function instead to calculate an average](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/googlespreadsheets/ss/2013-07-07-google-spreadsheet-average-function.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Mathias.  I was not aware of the XPath 1.0 limitation... and I hope Google extends Sheets to 2.0 or 3 in future.  I will read more on this, now that I know.  Much appreciated, and Kindest Regards,  G A